# SQL multiple join with where clause IN implode

Tags: php, sql

I have this sql query

```
$pole = array();
$pole[] = "test1";
$pole[] = "test2";

$pocet_k = count($pole);

    $query = "Select * from kategorie join recepty on recepty.kategorie_idkategorie=kategorie.idkategorie join druhy on druhy.iddruhy = recepty.druhy_iddruhy join recepty2suroviny on recepty_idrecepty=idrecepty join suroviny on idsuroviny=suroviny_idsuroviny WHERE suroviny.nazev_suroviny  IN (".implode(",", array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $pole)).") group by idrecepty having count(*)"."="."'$pocet_k'"." "."and druhy.iddruhy=recepty.druhy_iddruhy 
    order by recepty.nazev_receptu";
```

I am getting error `Unknown column 'test1' in 'where clause'` I don't know how to solve it :-/

Comment: Can you share the content of $query?  Also can you drop the MySQL/SQL Server tag.  They are different products which often require different solutions.

Comment: Well, like the error says, there is no `test1` column in the database table , which is the parameter you pass in the where statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with  `"  . $pocet_k .  "` and other minor ..

```
$pole = [];
$pole[] = ["test1"];
$pole[] = ["test2"];

$pocet_k = count($pole);

$query = "Select * from kategorie 
join recepty on recepty.kategorie_idkategorie=kategorie.idkategorie 
join druhy on druhy.iddruhy = recepty.druhy_iddruhy 
join recepty2suroviny on recepty_idrecepty=idrecepty 
join suroviny on idsuroviny=suroviny_idsuroviny 
WHERE suroviny.nazev_suroviny  IN (" . implode(",", array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $pole)).") 
group by idrecepty 
having count(*) =  " . $pocet_k . " and druhy.iddruhy=recepty.druhy_iddruhy 
order by recepty.nazev_receptu";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the part

```
IN (".implode(",", array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $pole)).")
```

Which results in

```
IN (test1, test2)
```

where `test1` and `test2` refer to columns, while you want them to refer to literals, that is

```
IN ('test1', 'test2')
```

So what might work for you is rewriting that part to

```
IN ('" . implode("','", array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $pole)) . "')
```

Which joins all elements with a `','` and wraps the result in `'` for edge cases.

But you really should think about using **binds**.